# Problems with sql MariaDB (1064)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I can't solve this error showing on my database:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE tf_links' at line 12

My SQL file code is:

```
CREATE TABLE tf_cookies (
  cid int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  uid int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  host VARCHAR(255) default NULL,
  data VARCHAR(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (cid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

--
-- tf_links
--
CREATE TABLE tf_links (
  lid int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL default '',
  sitename VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL default 'Old Link',
  sort_order TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (lid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Your code is fine (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=eaf1ed1225b1f611b28b565990a4217b), although using a string default value for an `int` is unorthodox.

Comment: For me, it worked! Any special invisible character in the original text, that was removed while pasting here? So copy this text, `diff` and try again.

Comment: I have lost my crystal ball, so I cannot see which tool (or program language) you use to execute the SQL statement.

Comment: How are you trying to execute these commands?  Some APIs do not allow multiple statements in a single query.